# Extract data from a website Jquery Grid

Tags: jquery, gridview, asp-classic

Hi I am trying to extarct  all phone numbers from the grid.

sancharsoft.bsnl.co.in/auction/vacant_nos/ch/gsm_choice.asp

Is there a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genuinely in two minds about even answering this, as it seems awfully off topic.

Simplest way I found was to open the page in chrome, load developer tools, reload the page, and then look for the POST request that requests the data, then you could forge that request with Curl, and then extract the data from the XML file that it returns.

Far easier than scraping it from the rendered grid.

```
Request URL:http://sancharsoft.bsnl.co.in/auction/vacant_nos/ch/fancy_nos_load.asp
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:65
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:ASPSESSIONIDSARRQQBT=EALMIDLAPLDHCEKDHIOKHHFG; PHPSESSID=88mr7i6gqis9u3ece750shjsg4
Host:sancharsoft.bsnl.co.in
Origin:http://sancharsoft.bsnl.co.in
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://sancharsoft.bsnl.co.in/auction/vacant_nos/ch/gsm_no_choice.asp
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.101 Safari/537.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview URL encoded
_search:false
nd:1357565939966
rows:50
page:1
sidx:gsmno
sord:asc
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:4605
Content-Type:text/xml; Charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 07 Jan 2013 13:38:59 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Returning

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><rows><page>1</page><total>48</total><records>2374</records><row id='9444011515'><cell><![CDATA[9444011515]]></cell><cell><![CDATA[843]]></cell></row><row id='9444018222'><cell><![CDATA[9444018222]]></cell><cell><![CDATA[843]]></cell></row><row id='9444026222'><cell><![CDATA[9444026222]]></cell><cell><![CDATA[843]]></cell></row></rows>
```

So.. To do this with curl..

```
curl -d "_search=false&nd=1357565939966&rows=50&page=1&sidx=gsmno&sord=asc" http://sancharsoft.bsnl.co.in/auction/vacant_nos/ch/fancy_nos_load.asp
```

As you can see, I've copied the exact browser request into the curl `-d " "` data specifier.

It turns out, that yes, you can actually change it so that "rows=50" becomes "rows=5000", and you get the expected buttload of data.  `<rows><page>1</page><total>1</total><records>2368</records>`

Actually, just over 2300 rows, but the thought works.

Comment: Thank you Tom. But i want all the numbers. At the bottom of the grid there is something like "View 1 - 50 of XXX XXX". Hot to retireve all XXX XXX numbers.

Comment: Tom i am not familiar with CURL commands. Can you give  me the command for the above requirement. I see "rows:50"  in the HTTP POST , i think i can increase row value like "rows:5000" to get all the data instead of page navigation.What is your suggestion?.

Comment: For future reference, see http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: when i tried i get  "couldn't connect to host at sancharsoft.bsnl.co.in:80" may be due to firewall in my company. Were you able to get  a response?.

Comment: I doubt it's your firewall, if  you managed to see the grid when you were using your browser..